# How to get UTF-8 codepoints of C# string?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I have a German string in C#

string s = "Menü";

I would like to get UTF-8 codepoints:

expected result:

```
\x4D\x65\x6E\xC3\xBC
```

The expected result has been verified via [online UTF-8 encoder/decoder](https://mothereff.in/utf-8) and via [Unicode code converter v8.1](https://mothereff.in/utf-8)

I tried a lot of conversion methods but I cannot get the expected result.

UPDATE:

Funny, the problem was not in the source code but in the wrong encoding in the input file :-) These answers helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Encoding.UTF8`, example below.

```
        string menu = "Menü";
        Console.WriteLine(menu);

        var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(menu);
        foreach(byte b in utfBytes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hex: {0:X}", b);
        }

        string menu2 = utf8.GetString(utfBytes, 0, utfBytes.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(menu2);
```

Comment: Using `string.Format(@"\x{0:X2}", item)` would be more accurate in terms of the question. But +1 for mentioning the hex string output

Answer (score 11):

There's no such thing as "UTF-8 codepoints" - there are UTF-8 code *units*, or Unicode code points.

In the string Menü, there are 4 code points:

- U+004D
- U+0065
- U+006E
- U+00FC

For BMP characters (i.e. those in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF) it's as simple as iterating over the `char` values in a string. For non-BMP characters that's slightly trickier. [`StringInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) looks helpful here, but it includes combining characters when iterating over text elements. It's not terribly hard to spot surrogate pairs in a string, but I don't *think* there's a very simple way of iterating over all the code points in a string.

Finding the UTF-8 code *units* - i.e. the UTF-8-encoded representation of a string as bytes, is simple:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

That will give you the five bytes you listed in your question: 0x4d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0xc3, 0xbc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly convert:

```
var utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Menü");
```

and `utf8` contains 0x4d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0xc3, 0xbc.